# What is the cause of this VS2017 .NET 4.7.2 C# 7.3 debug error and is there anything I can do to prevent it?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, runtime-error

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.8.0, targeting .NET 4.7.2 and C# language version 7.3 to create a console application which multi-threads using TPL.

Recently, when I have been debugging exceptions, Visual Studio has often frozen and then thrown the error message shown below.  Note: it is not a specific single segment of code which causes this error - the error happens when any exception is thrown.

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> To prevent an unsafe abort when evaluating the function
>   'System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadForm' all threads were allowed to run.
>   This may have changed the state of the process and any breakpoints
>   encountered may have been skipped.

What is the root cause of this error message and how can I prevent it from happening?

[image]

Comment: Any reason for asking here instead of posting the bug to Microsoft directly? Also, since you mention .NET 4.7.2 and c# 7.3, does it only happen with that setup?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes I am posting here because I am assuming I am doing something wrong rather than it being a bug.  However, in my 10 years experience of C#, I have never seen this one before... My applications rely on .NET 4.7.2 and C# 7.3 features so unfortunately I cannot compile against another version without major changes.  If no one can suggest a solution then I will do so anyway.

Comment: If possible, I would probably install VS 2015 and upgrade the framework/C# version (doable without too much work), and see if the error occurs there, before I would downport my code.  Despite some very excellent features in 2017, I'm still running 2015 because of numerous problems with 2017 across multiple computers and OSes (and languages, I might add).

Comment: I wouldn't describe that as an *error*, per se. It's telling you that some more things than you may have expected have just happened, so be cautious.

Comment: I have seen a similar issue on the Developer Community, MS reply it fixed at 15.8 preview 4, you can check it:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169170/155-evaluating-the-function-systemreflectionassemb.html

Comment: Still getting it in 15.9.